# Reasons why my string did not match regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords, exec, match

So lets say i have a variable containing a string, and i want to test whether it matches my regular expression or not, and i want to know which rule was broken when it returned false, is there a way i can get that?

Here's my code where i was testing

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$/;
var word = "dudeE1123123";

if(word.match(regex)){
    console.log("matched");
}else{
    console.log("did not match");
    console.log("i want to know why it did not match");
}
```

Reason i want this is that i want to notify my user that for example: "You did not include Uppercase character" or something like that

Comment: no way in javascript, short of writing your own regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is supposed to match some string of text. If it does not match, it does not keep any information about what was matched before the fail occurred. Thus, you cannot get any details on what caused a failure with your regex.

You can add some tests into the `else` block to see if the input string has no digits or letters. Something like this should be enough:

```js
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$/;
var word = "###";

if(word.match(regex)){
    console.log("matched");
}else{
    console.log("did not match");
    var msg = "";
    if (!/[a-zA-Z]/.test(word)) {                 // Are there any letters?
     msg += "Word has no ASCII letters. ";
    }
    if (!/\d/.test(word)) {                       // Are there any digits?
     msg += "Word has no digit. ";
    }
    if (word.length < 6) {                        // Is the length 6+?
        msg += "Word is less than 6 chars long. ";
    }
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: good idea i'll try this but it kinda sucks that javascript doesn't have that functionality tu show you where it mismatched

Comment: I doubt there are such regex flavors that show you that. In Perl, `use re 'debug';` is a way to check where a fail occurred, but the output  is rather messy for a layman. Python `re.DEBUG` is much less verbose and rather useless for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i see you can do that is by filtering in the "else" block trying to look for the reason. this is a (not complete and not 100% valid) example:

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$/;
var specialCharsCheckRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
var word = "dude1123123";
var word2 = "$dude1123123";

if(word.match(regex)){
    console.log("matched");
}else{
    console.log("did not match");
    if(!word.match(specialCharsCheckRegex)){
        console.log("it contained special chars");
    }else{
    console.log("i want to know why it did not match");
    }
}
```